# Minimize all window in mac but every time one window is active

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstatusitem, nsapplication

I have added a code to minimize all the running application on NSStatusItem, its a very simple code

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] hideOtherApplications];
```

But when i run this application then one application is always on the desktop the one with whom the user is currently interacting. I have also tried

```
[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] hide];
```

and

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication]hideOtherApplications:self];
```

and even one for those who would suggest me apple script well i have tried that too but no luck may be i got the script wrong don't know

but still the same issue persists, am not able to point out why every time with NSStatusItem one app remains.
Please help me out on this.

Comment: If you use hideOtherApplications, documentation clealy says "The user can hide all applications except the current one by Command-Option-clicking on an application’s Dock icon" i.e. except the active.

Comment: @rahul: Then what should i do to hide all the application any guidance on that.

Comment: :Honestly, I don't know. I was trying to narrow down your approach. But, If you can add more details like why you need to do this, what are you doing, may be you will get better response. Also check with Apple Human Interface guidelines if it has anything to say on this.

Answer (score -1):

Use this combination altogether: **Option + Command + H + M**